# Multiple handles in firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a chat app with rooms feature in iOS, and had built a Firebase data design like this:

```
"members" : {
  "userId1" : {
    "roomId1" : true
  },
  "userId2" : {
    "roomId1" : true
  }
}
"rooms" : {
  "roomId1" : {
    "lastMessage" : "Last message",
    "timeStamp" : 1494483604,
    //users in this room
    "users" : {
      "userId1" : true,
      "usreId2" : true
    }
  }
}
```

So to show list of conversations of a user, firstly I observe single event of type value of path `members/userId` to get list of rooms that user take part in.

Then for each `roomId`, I observe `rooms/roomId` to get data to show on the UI.

The question is if a user takes part in a great deal of rooms, is observing changes for all of them best practice ?

For example, if I have 30 conversations from `roomId1` to `roomId30`, I want to update the latest messages on the UI whenever changes happened, is observing 30 references makes sense ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not best practice but it's a practice that works. However, based on your structure it would be simpler to generate a query on the rooms node for any users/userIdx: true.

That will add and observer to one node and notify the app of any changes to rooms the user is part of.

For example

Given a structure

```
rooms
  room_0
    room_name: "My Room"
    users:
      uid_0: true
      uid_1: true
      uid_2: true
  room_1
    room_name: "Romper Room"
    users:
      uid_0: true
      uid_2: true
```

and some code to add an observer to watch for uid_1

```
let roomsRef = self.ref.child("rooms")

roomsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "users/uid_1").queryEqual(toValue: true)
        .observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
     let roomDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
     let roomName = roomDict["room_name"] as! String
     print(roomName)
})
```

When this code is first run, it will print out

```
My Room
```

because the user is part of My Room (room_0) and not part of room_1.

If you then add uid_1: true to room_1 it will print

```
Romper Room
```

Comment: I used to query like that. But Firebase will keep warning about performance because `room_0/users/uid_0` is not indexed yet (It is generated in runtime). I don't really know it could be scaled with thousands of users or not. Hope to hear answer from you.

Comment: @TonyNguyen You can add indexing at any level of your structure via Firebase Rules. It's fairly straightforward and once you add an index to the rules, the warning will no longer appear. See [Index Your Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data). I wouldn't be too concerned about indexing with a small dataset. My answer is scalable to tens of thousands of users so when you get to that level it will definitely need indexing.

Comment: Yes, I indexed those dynamic keys successfully. That link you provided just had simple examples. Thank you :)

Comment: @TonyNguyen If my answer helped you, it may help others so be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `observe` to update db changes, so you can update UI based on the observation.
Take a look at this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write